# Using XPath to locate on a button within a table

Tags: xpath

I have a table with several columns.  The first column contains unique data, the 5th contains three buttons (Edit, Assignments and Delete).

I would like to use an XPath expression to locate on the edit button for one of the rows by indentifying the row using the unique data from column one (think that made sense).

I have built some expressions which will allow me to locate on the first column and edit button independantly as follows:

```
//td[text()='Managers']
```

and

```
tr[2]//button[text()='Edit']
```

The closest I can get to doing what I want is:

```
//td[text()='Managers'] | //tr[2]//button[text()='Edit']
```

...However this will locate on the data/button in column 1 AND 5 at the same time, what I want is just for the button in column 5.

The reason I want to do it this way, is so later I can pass in 'Managers' as a varaible in order to select the row (as its unique and meaningful data), and then press the edit button in a different column on that row.

Hope this makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: please include example data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't very clear as posted, especially because I can't see any relevant part of the HTML. But if I understand this correctly, you can try to select the row that has `Manager` in it then get corresponding `Edit` button like so :

```
//tr[.//td='Managers']//button[.='Edit']
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback har07, I appreciate I need to work on phrasing my questions.  Your suggestion works for the Edit and Delete button perfectly, needed a slight adjustment for Assignments as it turns out its not a button, but got there with //tr[.//td='Managers'] // a[.='Assignments'].  Thanks again, thats a great help!

Comment: just for clarification to user using // in xpath selects elements anywhere under the previous selector in your case you might be able to use a single /

Comment: //tr[./td='Managers'] // button[.='Edit'] worked.  Stoppped working If I removed anymore '/'.